# ¿Si alguien "Malicioso" sabe la dirección (url) o en que carpeta de mi servidor tengo un .php lo puede descargar y ver el código?

Tags: php, php7

De ser así ¿hay alguna forma para "proteger" o dificultar esto?

Comment: Se supone que tu servidor web no devuelve directamente tus ficheros .php. Lo que hace cuando recibe una petición, es leer tu fichero php, ejecutarlo y devolver el resultado al cliente. Lo que no hace el servidor (salvo fallo o que algo este mal configurado) es devolver tu fichero php en limpio, sería algo muy grave. En general con la configuración por defecto y con versiones estables esto no debería ocurrirte.

Comment: El servidor que he contratado funciona muy bien... ¿La empresa de hosting que he contratado se encarga de proteger los archivos del lado del servidor cierto? o ¿Debo independientemente implementar más medidas de seguridad?

Comment: La empresa debería garantizarte que solo quien tenga permisos pueda ver el contenido de los ficheros php en limpio. Implementar más medidas de seguridad dependerá de lo valioso que sea lo que quieres proteger. ¿Solo quieres proteger el código en sí? o hay datos importantes hardocodeados como contraseñas, datos confindenciales, etc.? Si solo es código, hay que plantearse ¿a alguien le va a valer este código para algo? Si son otro tipo de datos podrías considerar incluir más medidas de seguridad como el cifrado de esos datos

Comment: ¡Te comprendo perfecto! Solo es proteger código... Buscare la forma de cifrar para tener mayor seguridad. ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que PHP trabaja de lado de servidor, por lo qué la brecha de seguridad para ver el código es acceder al servidor donde se encuentre este source code.

Podrías intentar por ejemplo:

- ejecutar un wget a la URL de este fichero PHP que tengas: solamente
  te extrae el contenido "frontend", e.g: código html.
- Ejecutar un file_get_contents desde PHP:

```
$página_inicio = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $página_inicio;
```

Sucederá lo mismo.

La forma de proteger esto, es proteger el acceso al código fuente en el servidor.

Comment: ¿Y esto lo protege la empresa a la que le he contratado el hosting? o ¿Puedo independientemente implementar mas medidas de seguridad?

Comment: Las empresas de hosting suelen tener sus médidas de seguridad. Dependiendo de la empresa, pueden tener cientos de miles de hosting. En Dinahosting por ejemplo tenemos muy buenas médidas de seguridad para esto. Luego, puedes por tu cuenta, quizá puedas hacer algunas mejoras. Pero todo recae principalmente en la configuración que tenga el servidor.

Comment: Un ejemplo podría ser acceso al servidor por consola, lo más seguro es que lo tengan protegido para acceder por contraseñas por ejemplo, o para acceder desde X direcciones IP, etc. Es lo más seguro para empresas con cientos de miles de cliente, securizar lo más que puedan.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias Adrian por tu ayuda!

Comment: A ti. Cualquier duda aquí estamos.